# On a button press to scroll through an array, my app crashes

Tags: arrays, swift, button, uiimageview

When I press `nextImage1` in the simulator, I get an error saying:

> [Project_BodySwapp.ViewController nextImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ffe4660a1e0'

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var imageNames1 = ["doghead","uk"]
var imageNames2 = ["macawLower","us"]
var pickedImage = String()
var currentImage = 0

@IBOutlet weak var displayImage: UIImageView!
//212x138
@IBOutlet weak var displayImage2: UIImageView!
//212x334


//BUTTON FUNCTIONALITY
//UPPER
@IBAction func randomizeImage(_ sender: Any) {
    displayImage.image = UIImage(named: (produceRandomValue(imageNames1)))
}

@IBAction func nextImage1(_ sender: Any) {
    currentImage += 1
    displayImage.image = UIImage(named: imageNames1[currentImage])
}

@IBAction func previousImage1(_ sender: Any) {


}



//LOWER
@IBAction func randomizeImage2(_ sender: Any) {

    displayImage2.image = UIImage(named: (produceRandomValue(imageNames2)))
}



func randomFromZero(to number: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(number)))
}

func produceRandomValue(_ array: [String]) -> String {
    let randomIndex = randomFromZero(to: array.count)
    let pickedImage = imageNames1[randomIndex]
    return pickedImage
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Read the error closely. Look at your code closely. Notice the problem?

Comment: I'll keep looking, I was afraid it was something obvious

Comment: If it's obvious, why do you need to keep looking? Simply fix the name of the method.

Comment: ....to look at my code...to notice the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your button's action `touchUpInside` has been set as `nextImage` but in your code you don't have that. You have `nextImage1` instead. Recheck the Connections Inspector.

[image]